# How can people get to level 20 without a team?

Tags: pokemon-go

I thought players must choose a team when they get to level 5, however I've seen high level accounts for sale on eBay without a team chosen.

How is it possible to play without choosing a team?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will be asked to join a team when entering a gym for the first time after reaching level 5. So if you don't enter any gym you can play without team.

Comment: But while playing I was asked right after I've reached lvl 5. I didn't go to a  gym. (v 0.29.2 for Android)

Comment: I had to enter a gym in order to choose a team. I'll look into it. Maybe Niantic changed something.

Comment: Nobody I knew was prompted to join a team until they clicked on a gym so I agree with dly on this one.

Answer (score 3):

If you hit the 'back' button on Android when first presented with the lvl 5 "join a team!" prompt, you just dump back out into normal play. You can do this any time you tap on a gym and are presented with the same "join a team!" screen until you decide on which team to join.

I did this on my daughter's iPhone as well, so it's not just an Android thing. Just can't remember what I had to do to back out.

Comment: Odd. I never got any prompts to join a team when I reached Level 5.

Answer (score -1):

On iPhone, if you enter a gym and are prompted to choose team, just hit the home button, thus leaving the game. Then close/kill the app through the app switcher. When you re-enter the game you are back on the "street" again (without the team prompt).

Answer (score -1):

Before the update the professor prompted to join a team right after I hit level 5 I joined the Pokemon trainer club with same account and it hasn't prompted. I'm sure it isn't because of the account log in. (Email or pokemon trainer club) maybe the gym prompt caused bugs not sure but yeah

Comment: Um... So, what's the answer to the question here? Works differently after update?